# laravel class user not found en Controller y si en Tinker

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy relacionando User con sigo mismo, en Tinker funciona todo bien me crea un registro en la tabla pivote

```
 ejemplo en Tinker todo OK
  $p=App\User::find(246)
  $u=App\User::find(247)
  $u->addParent($p)
```

Pero en el controlador NO funciona da error

> "class User not found"

```
    public function parents()


{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'parent_user', 'user_id','parent_id' 
 );
}

public function addParent(User $user)
{       
    $this->parents()->attach($user->id);

}
```

Comment: en la parte superior importaste el namespace? así use App\User; ?

Comment: Hola si, la diferencia para solucionarlo fue colocar esto  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class  en lugar de esto  return $this->belongsToMany('/User'  Gracias por responder